# How can I get `git rebase` to list the conflicting files again?

Tags: git

The first time I do a `git rebase branchname`, I get a list of files which contain conflicts.

I then type some other command that blasts a lot of output, scrolling my output up.

**How can I now reproduce the list of conflicting files?**

I have tried `git rebase` and `git rebase --continue`, but neither will list the conflicting files again.

```
$ git rebase                                                       
A rebase is in progress, try --continue, --skip or --abort.        
$ git rebase --continue                                            
You must edit all merge conflicts and then                         
mark them as resolved using git add                                
[hq6@rcmaster ramcloud] 2014-08-12 14:30:49
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in the middle of a rebase, you can run `git status` to see the current state of all your files, including ones with conflicts.